# CodenameOne: problems using REST PATCH call

Tags: rest, codenameone

I am trying to use the Rest.patch call in CodenameOne but I am getting nothing back. If I use a REST client like [ARC](https://install.advancedrestclient.com) I get a response code of 200 and I can see the change has been made.

The Network Monitor in the CN1 Simulator shows the request being sent but shows no reply either.

Here is the code I use in CN1, Rest.post and Rest.get work well elsewhere in the code, it is Rest.patch that I am having a problem with?

```
bodyString= "{\"Exported\":\"1\"," +
             "\"Notes\":\"Order sent\"}";

Response<Map> jsonData = Rest.patch(URL + "Orders(%27" + orderNumber + "%27)").
                            jsonContent().
                            header("Authorization", authorisation).
                            header("Alias", alias).
                            body(bodyString).
                            getAsJsonMap();

int responseCode = jsonData.getResponseCode();
```

If I send a Rest.put or Rest.post request instead, I get a 404 error, this is from either ARC or CN1.

Comment: Are you using the Network Monitor of the Simulator? What code do you use in Codename One? What request do you do with ARC?

Comment: FYI Patch is wired in Codename One to pass arguments in the body similar to POST/PUT

Comment: I have just noticed the error in the IntelliJ console that says "Exception: java.net.ProtocolException - Invalid HTTP method: PATCH", does this help?